# How many Azure SignalR Resources do I need?

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, signalr, azure-signalr

We are going to implement a chat feature within our application using Azure SignalR Service. This will be our first attempt at using SignalR.

We have also identified other areas of our application that can make use of SignalR, but those areas are not related to the chat feature.

Is it advised to create a Azure SignalR resource for each logically structured feature/area? Or will a single Azure SignalR resource handle it all?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale your Azure SignalR resource to handle a large volume of traffic but keep in mind that you can only specify the Azure SignalR connection string in one place at startup.  So, if you did need even more resources, you would need to host multiple web apps to supply this kind of resource division.  You would also need to design it such that the application does not need to share the SignalR connection between the features/areas of your app.

My advice would be to start with the serverless Azure SignalR service and scale it until you start to reach a capacity limit which will depend heavily on your implementation and intelligently sending messages to the appropriate clients.

Comment: Is the web app(s) you mention the one that is connecting to signalR and is processing the messages that is traveling thru the signalR connection?

Comment: Yes, @Jared that's correct.